# kcachegrind: How to draw the full call graph?

Tags: kcachegrind

I like kcachegrind's call graph. But I have been unable to make it graph the full call graph.

I would imagine I just had to set:

1. Graph > Caller Depth > Unlimited
2. Graph > Callee Depth > Unlimited
3. Graph > Min. Node Cost > No Minimum
4. Graph > Min. Call Cost > No Minimum

1 and 2 are easy. 3 is in the memu, but grayed out. 4 is not in the menu.

Is there a way I can make it show the full call graph graphically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer for that lies in the [source code (line 2794)](https://quickgit.kde.org/?p=kcachegrind.git&a=blob&h=bfcf398bafc032c3f140e326f488a0d52cfef159&hb=3272232b08949b9c8aa1e3e63ebef4884c3a3770&f=libviews%2Fcallgraphview.cpp):

```
a = addNodeLimitAction(m, tr("No Minimum"), 0.0);
// Unlimited node cost easily produces huge graphs such that 'dot'
// would need a long time to layout. For responsiveness, we only allow
// for unlimited node cost if a caller and callee depth limit is set.
a->setEnabled((_maxCallerDepth>=0) && (_maxCalleeDepth>=0));
```

So you have to set the other two options to value other than 'unlimited'.