# Make callgrind show all function calls in the kcachegrind callgraph

Tags: valgrind, callgrind, kcachegrind

I was using valgrind tool - callgrind and kcachegrind for profiling a large project and was wondering if there is a way that callgrind reports the stats from all the functions (not just the most expensive functions).

To be specific - When I visualized the callgraph in kcachegrind, it included only those functions that are quite expensive, but I was wondering if there is a way to include all the functions from the project in the callgraph. Command used for generating profiling info is given below :

```
valgrind --dsymutil=yes --tool=callgrind $EXE
```

I am not sure if I have to give any options to valgrind or may be compile the application at a different optimization. This might be something trivial but I couldn't find a solution. Any pointers regarding this highly appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: Kcachegrind will hide functions with small weight (some limits can be changed with main menu - settings - like count of items in lists; some - with context menu on graph tabs). You can also try `callgrind_annotate` console tool which has no limits.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

It occurred to me yesterday. As shown in the picture, I found in call graph of kcachegrind, there is a right click menu, in which you can set up the threshold above which the node will be visualized.

There is also a option "no minimum", however it can not be chosen. I think maybe it's because, if every function, no matter how trivial it is, takes up a node, the graph may be too large to handle.

I just found that the script [gprof2dot](https://github.com/jrfonseca/gprof2dot) can handle this.
The script can convert the output of callgrind to dot, which can be visualized as graph. The script has two relevant parameters:

- `-n PERCENTAGE, --node-thres=PERCENTAGE` to eliminate nodes below this threshold [default: 0.5]. In order to visualize all nodes in the graph, you can set the parameter like `-n0`
- `-e PERCENTAGE`, `--edge-thres=PERCENTAGE`to eliminate edges below this threshold [default: 0.1]. In order to visualize all edges in the graph, you can set the parameter like `-e0`

In order to generate the complete call graph you would use both of the options (`-n0` and `-e0`).

I've tried this, however, as the graph generated is too large, the dot software warned me that "graph is too large for cairo-renderer bitmaps. Scaling by 0.328976 to fit. " But you can set up the output format as eps which can handle this. You also can change the parameter to adapt your objective.

## Example

Let's say that you have a callgrind output file called `callgrind.out.1992`. To generate a complete call graph you would use:

`gprof2dot.py -n0 -e0 ./callgrind.out.1992 -f callgrind`

To generate a `PNG` output image of the graph, you could run the following commands:

`gprof2dot -n0 -e0 ./callgrind.out.1992 -f callgrind > out.dot`

`dot -Tpng out.dot -o out.png`

Now you have an `out.png` image with the full graph.

Note the usage of the `-f` parameter to specify the profile format (`callgrind` in our case).

Comment: can't comment yet, here's the solution to > There is also a option "no minimum", however it can not be chosen. from rengar's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29449548/kcachegrind-how-to-draw-the-full-call-graph

Answer (score 7):

The command I am using is
`valgrind --tool=callgrind --dump-instr=yes --collect-jumps=yes $EXE` and as far as I have seen it includes all the functions in the call graph.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to complete rengar's answer with information that will allow you to generate the **complete call graph**, as well as give an example of the full process.

You can use the [gprof2dot](https://github.com/jrfonseca/gprof2dot) to show all functions in a callgraph. The script can convert the output of callgrind to [dot](http://www.graphviz.org/), which can be visualized as graph. The script has two relevant parameters:

- `-n PERCENTAGE`, `--node-thres=PERCENTAGE` to eliminate nodes below this threshold [default: `0.5`]. In order to visualize all nodes in the graph you should set this parameter to `-n0`
- `-e PERCENTAGE`, `--edge-thres=PERCENTAGE`to eliminate edges below this threshold [default: `0.1`]. In order to visualize all edges in the graph you should set this parameter to `-e0`

In order to generate the **complete call graph** you would use both of the options: `-n0` and `-e0`.

## Example

Let's say that you have a callgrind output file called `callgrind.out.1992`. To generate a complete call graph you would use:

`gprof2dot -n0 -e0 ./callgrind.out.1992 -f callgrind`

To generate a PNG output image of the graph, you could run the following commands:

`gprof2dot -n0 -e0 ./callgrind.out.1992 -f callgrind > out.dot`

`dot -Tpng out.dot -o out.png`

Now you have an `out.png` image with the full graph.

Note the usage of the `-f` parameter to specify the profile format (`callgrind` in our case).