# KCachegrind output for optimized vs unoptimized builds

Tags: c++, optimization, valgrind, kcachegrind

I run `valgrind --tool=callgrind ./executable` on the executable file generated by the following code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

class XYZ{
public:
    int Count() const {return count;}
    void Count(int val){count = val;}
private:
    int count;
};

int main() {
    XYZ xyz;
    xyz.Count(10000);
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < xyz.Count(); i++){
//My interest is to see how the compiler optimizes the xyz.Count() call
        sum += i;
    }
    printf("Sum is %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

I make a `debug` build with the following options: `-fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -fexceptions -g -std=c++14`. The `release` build is with the following options: `-fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -fexceptions -g -O2 -std=c++14`.

Running valgrind generates two dump files. When these files (one file for debug executable, the other for release executable) are viewed in KCachegrind, the debug build is understandable as shown below:

[image: Debug Build]

As expected, the function `XYZ::Count() const` is called 10001 times. However, the optimized release build is much harder to decipher and it is not clear how many times the function is called at all. I am aware that the function call might be `inlined`. But how does one figure out that it has infact been inlined? The callgraph for the release build is as shown below:

[image: Release Build]

There seems to be no indication of function `XYZ::Count() const` at all from `main()`.

My questions are:

(1)Without looking at the assembly language code generated by the debug/release builds, and by using using KCachegrind, how can one figure out how many times a particular function, (in this case `XYZ::Count() const`) is called? In the release build call graph above, the function is not even called once.

(2)Is there a way to understand the callgraph and other details provided by KCachegrind for release/optimized builds? I have already looked at the KCachegrind manual available at https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kdesdk/kcachegrind/kcachegrind.pdf, but I was wondering if there are some useful hacks/rules of thumb that one should look for in release builds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of valgrind is easy to understand: As valgrind+kcachegrind are telling you, this function was not called at all in the release build.

The question is, what do you mean by called? If a function is inlined, is it still "called"? Actually, the situation is more complex, as it seems at the first sight and your example isn't that trivial.

Was `Count()` inlined in the release build? Sure, kind of. The code transformation during the optimization is often quite remarkable, like in your case - and the best way to judge, is to look into the resulting  [assembler](https://godbolt.org/g/ufGGFi) (here for clang):

```
main:                                   # @main
        pushq   %rax
        leaq    .L.str(%rip), %rdi
        movl    $49995000, %esi         # imm = 0x2FADCF8
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        callq   printf@PLT
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        popq    %rcx
        retq
.L.str:
        .asciz  "Sum is %d\n"
```

You can see, that the `main` doesn't execute the for-loop at all, but just prints the result (`49995000`), which is calculated during the optimization because the number of iterations is known during the compile-time.

So was `Count()` inlined? Yes, somewhere during the first steps of optimization, but then the code became something completely different - there is no place where `Count()` was inlined in the final assembler.

So what happens, when we "hide" the number of iteration from compiler? E.g. pass it via the command line:

```
...
int main(int argc,  char* argv[]) {
   XYZ xyz;
   xyz.Count(atoi(argv[1]));
...
```

In the resulting [assembler](https://godbolt.org/g/uHTRSw), we still don't encounter a for-loop, because the optimizer can figure out, that the call of `Count()` doesn't have side-effect and optimizes the whole thing out:

```
main:                                   # @main
        pushq   %rbx
        movq    8(%rsi), %rdi
        xorl    %ebx, %ebx
        xorl    %esi, %esi
        movl    $10, %edx
        callq   strtol@PLT
        testl   %eax, %eax
        jle     .LBB0_2
        leal    -1(%rax), %ecx
        leal    -2(%rax), %edx
        imulq   %rcx, %rdx
        shrq    %rdx
        leal    -1(%rax,%rdx), %ebx
.LBB0_2:
        leaq    .L.str(%rip), %rdi
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        movl    %ebx, %esi
        callq   printf@PLT
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        popq    %rbx
        retq
.L.str:
        .asciz  "Sum is %d\n"
```

The optimizer came up with the formula `(n-1)*(n-2)/2` for the sum `i=0..n-1`!

Let's now hide the definition of `Count()` in an separate translation unit `class.cpp`, so the optimizer cannot see it's definition:

```
class XYZ{
public:
    int Count() const;//definition in separate translation unit
...
```

Now we get our for-loop and a call to `Count()` in every iteration, the most important part of [the assembler](https://godbolt.org/g/3Vd8HX) is:

```
.L6:
        addl    %ebx, %ebp
        addl    $1, %ebx
.L3:
        movq    %r12, %rdi
        call    XYZ::Count() const@PLT
        cmpl    %eax, %ebx
        jl      .L6
```

The result of the `Count()` (in `%rax`) is compared to the current counter (in `%ebx`) in every iteration step. Now, if we run it with valgrind we can see in the list of callees, that `XYZ::Count()` was called `10001` times.

However, for modern tool-chains it is not enough to see the assembler of the single translation units - there is a thing called `link-time-optimization`. We can use it by building somewhere along these lines:

```
gcc -fPIC -g -O2 -flto -o class.o -c class.cpp
gcc -fPIC -g -O2 -flto -o test.o  -c test.cpp
gcc -g -O2 -flto -o test_r class.o test.o
```

And running the resulting executable with valgrind we once again see, that `Count()` was not called!

However looking into the machine code (here I used gcc, my clang-installation seems to have an issue with lto):

```
00000000004004a0 <main>:
  4004a0:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  4004a4:   48 8b 7e 08             mov    0x8(%rsi),%rdi
  4004a8:   ba 0a 00 00 00          mov    $0xa,%edx
  4004ad:   31 f6                   xor    %esi,%esi
  4004af:   e8 bc ff ff ff          callq  400470 <strtol@plt>
  4004b4:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  4004b6:   7e 2b                   jle    4004e3 <main+0x43>
  4004b8:   89 c1                   mov    %eax,%ecx
  4004ba:   31 d2                   xor    %edx,%edx
  4004bc:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  4004be:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
  4004c0:   01 c2                   add    %eax,%edx
  4004c2:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
  4004c5:   39 c8                   cmp    %ecx,%eax
  4004c7:   75 f7                   jne    4004c0 <main+0x20>
  4004c9:   48 8d 35 a4 01 00 00    lea    0x1a4(%rip),%rsi        # 400674 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
  4004d0:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
  4004d5:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  4004d7:   e8 a4 ff ff ff          callq  400480 <__printf_chk@plt>
  4004dc:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  4004de:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  4004e2:   c3                      retq   
  4004e3:   31 d2                   xor    %edx,%edx
  4004e5:   eb e2                   jmp    4004c9 <main+0x29>
  4004e7:   66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```

We can see, that the call to the function `Count()` was inlined but  - there is still a for-loop (I guess this is a gcc vs clang thing).

But what is of most interest to you:  the function `Count()` is "called" only once - its value is saved to register `%ecx` and the loop is actually only:

```
  4004c0:   01 c2                   add    %eax,%edx
  4004c2:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
  4004c5:   39 c8                   cmp    %ecx,%eax
  4004c7:   75 f7                   jne    4004c0 <main+0x20>
```

This all you could also see with  help of Kcachegrid, if valgrind were run with option `--dump-instr=yes.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Looks like I should just do normal C++ coding and not worry too much about whether the compiler in fact does what it is supposed to do in release builds. I will refer back to this and look at asm of release builds just to satisfy my curiosity in future.

Answer (score 0):

search in the callgrind.out file for XYZ::Count() to see if valgrind recorded any events for this function.

```
grep "XYZ::Count()" callgrind.out | more
```

if you find the function name in the callgrind file, then important to know that kcachegrind hides functions with small weight.
see the answers at: [Make callgrind show all function calls in the kcachegrind callgraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769323/make-callgrind-show-all-function-calls-in-the-kcachegrind-callgraph)

Comment: the release .out file contains no instance of Count(), but the debug .out does contain Count()

Comment: this is not without looking asm, but in valgrind manual: "If you want to be able to see assembly code level annotation, specify --dump-instr=yes. This will produce profile data at instruction granularity. Note that the resulting profile data can only be viewed with KCachegrind. For assembly annotation, it also is interesting to see more details of the control flow inside of functions, i.e. (conditional) jumps. This will be collected by further specifying --collect-jumps=yes."